# How to implement database search like this with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am working on my first website using Ruby on Rails. The idea is a nutrition "search engine", where you search for a food and then the web app takes you to either a page with nutrition information about that food or a page of search results if no exact match exists.

So far, I have created the nutrition information database (using Postgresql) and added some test data. This is the command I used to create the scaffolding for the database:

```
rails generate scaffold Food name:string calories:decimal portion_name:string \
portion:decimal image_url:string description:text
```

I then created the index page. This is the command I used to create the index:

```
rails generate controller home index
```

I removed `public/index.html` and modified `config/routes.rb` to contain this line:

```
root :to => 'home#index'
```

After this, I added the search form to `app/views/home/index.html.erb`, like so:

```
<div id="search">
  <h1>How many calories are in... ?</h1>
  <%= form_tag("/search", :method => "get") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag "q", nil, :class => "span6" %>
    <%= submit_tag("Go", :name => nil) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Now, I would like to hook up this search form so that, if there is an exact match to the search query or one near match, the user is routed directly to a page displaying information (from the database) for that food. If there isn't an exact match, I would like the user to be presented with a page of results and links to the nutrition page for each result.

How can I implement this functionality? I have tried googling for articles about implementing search with Rails and I have watched a screencast, also, but none of the resources I have found are implementing quite what I want.

Here's a GitHub link to the project so far: https://github.com/robertseaton/nutrition-project.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Thinking-Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/) for searching in Rails - [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) is an open source search server. You can define how you want your search to work right in Rails.

Comment: I am only interested in searching one field, so I think using Sphinx would be overkill.

Comment: Are you going to index the field? If you are going to search by any word in the 'name' field and if you want scalability, you'll need to keep an index of the words in that field. That's what Sphinx does (among other things). If you don't index the individual words but want to search by them, you'll end up sequentially scanning every word in that column.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sunspot to cater to your needs of the search. Here is the github link of sunspot https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot .

Using sunspot you can specify what all items are going to be searchable like food, calories etc. and also give various weights to these items so that if there is a keyword match lets say between food and protien which result should be displayed at the top.

sunspot wiki at github has got lot of resources to get you started and it is very intuitive to implement :).

Thanks,